# Does an implicit typecast in Java have an effect on the order of operations?

Tags: java, if-statement, implicit-conversion, order-of-execution, relational-operators

I have a snippet from my code where a statement that seems like it should evaluate to "false" actually returns true.

```
        long composite = -1L;
        
        ArrayList<Long> primes = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> squares = new ArrayList<Long>();
        squares.add(1L);
        primes.add(2L);
        primes.add(3L);
        
        for (long i = 4; composite == -1L; i++) {
            double sqrt_max = Math.sqrt((double) i); 
            if (sqrt_max == (int) sqrt_max) squares.add(i);
            if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
            boolean prime = true;
            for (int j = 0; primes.get(j) <= sqrt_max; j++) { 
                if (i % primes.get(j) == 0) {// number is not prime
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (prime) { // number is prime
                primes.add(i);
            }
            else {
                boolean conjTrue = false;
                for (Long l : primes) {
                    ListIterator<Long> it = squares.listIterator(squares.size() - 1);
                    while (it.hasPrevious()) {
                        long m = it.previous();
                        if (l + 2L * m == i) {
                            conjTrue = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (l + 2L * m < i) break;
                    }
                    if (conjTrue) break;
                }
                if (!conjTrue) composite = i;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nAnswer: " + composite);
```

As it stands, this code works fine (I finished debugging), but I found a problem that I could not explain and I wanted to learn.

The relational statement `else if (l + 2L * m < i)`, when the variables evaluate to `(19 + 2 * 9 < 27)` -> `(38 < 27)` (obviously false) would evaluate to `true` if the code was instead `else if (l + 2 * m < i)`. Note the 2L is replaced with a 2 (int). I even used a print statement directly after the `else if` to test the value of the `boolean` `l + 2 * m < i` and would get `true`.

Something about being within the `else if` conditional parentheses and the implicit typecast caused the relation to erroneously evaluate to `true`. Within other contexts it would compute correctly. What could cause this issue?

Comment: I run your code and i get the same result in both variants, with false in case which you are describing

Comment: re: *(19 + 2 * 9 < 27) -> (38 < 27)*  FWIW, the left-hand side of the inequality evaluates to 37.  Which doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you didn't write `else if (1 + 2 * m < i)` ?  A lower-case `l` is usually a poor choice of identifier for precisely that reason.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify your question,

It seems that you are suggesting that

```
    Long l = 19L;
    Long m = 9L;
    long i = 27;
    System.out.println(l + 2L * m < i);
```

would print true.

**output**

```
false
```

Comment: I think he's actually saying that while `l + 2L * m < i` correctly evaluates to false,  `l + 2 * m < i` results in true.  This cannot be the case, because apart from anything else, `2 * m` is long arithmetic by virtue of the type of `m`'.  And even if `m` were `int` we'd still have the same result.